# Custom taxonomy terms registered not showing when added in child theme

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have registered a new custom post type and taxonoy in my child theme using following code:

```
add_action('init', 'tours_register');
function tours_register() {
    $slug = 'tour';
    $labels = array(
        'name' => $slug,
        'singular_name' => $slug,
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'themewaves'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Tour', 'themewaves'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Tour', 'themewaves'),
        'new_item' => __('New Tour', 'themewaves'),
        'all_items' => __('All Tours', 'themewaves'),
        'view_item' => __('View Tour', 'themewaves'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Tours', 'themewaves'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No Tour found', 'themewaves'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Tour found in Trash', 'themewaves'),
        'menu_name' => __('Tours', 'themewaves')
    );    
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,

        'menu_icon' => THEME_DIR . '/framework/assets/images/portfolio.png',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $slug),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor','page-attributes','thumbnail','revisions','comments','custom-fields')
    );
    register_post_type('tw_tour', $args);
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function custom_tour_taxonomy(){
    $slug = 'tour';
    register_taxonomy("cat_tour", array("tw_tour"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => __("Categories", "themewaves"), "singular_label" => __("Tour Category", "themewaves"), 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $slug.'_cat')));
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_tour_taxonomy' );
```

After that, I have to create a new element in the theme's page builder to show this custom post type.
In that element somewhere in the code, I have added this to fetch the categories:

```
//Tour Catigories
$tours = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'cat_tour',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));
$tour_categories = array("0" => "Select Category");
if(!empty($tours)) {
    foreach ($tours as $tour) {
        $tour_categories["$tour->term_id"] = $tour->name;
    }
}
```

And then I have to add those categories like this:

```
"recent_tours" => array(
        "name" => "Tour Carousel",
        "size" => "size-1-1",
        "only" => "builder",
        "settings" => array(
            "tour_category" => array(
                "title" => "Tour category",
                "type" => "category",
                "options" => $tour_categories,
                "default" => "0",
                "desc" => "Chosen categories will be included.",
            ));
```

But the issue is `$tour_categories` is not showing any data if I'm adding the CPT function in child theme. If I am adding same function in main theme, then the categories start showing. But I just want to figure it out why it is not working through child theme.

Any help in troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but do not run `flush_rewrite_rules();` on the `init` hook. This function should only be run once. Either manually flush them in settings, or add some logic to check if they've already been flushed before doing it again.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Sure, thank you for this advice !

Answer (score 0):

For register taxonomy change:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_tour_taxonomy' );
```

to:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_tour_taxonomy' );
```

Check: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Basic_Example